# Accessing multiple stacks using struct in c

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, stack

To be specific, I wanted to access multiple stacks with the purpose in mind to pop an element from one stack and push it into the other stack. So, I decided to access them using **structures** (*struct*). Consider the following code,

```
    #define MAX 100
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    struct bag
    {
    int top;
    int arr[MAX];
    }harry,monk;

    int pop(struct bag name);
    void push(int data,struct bag name);

    int main()
    {
    int i,temp;
    harry.top=-1;
    monk.top=-1;
    push(3,harry);
    push(1,harry);
    push(1,harry);
    push(4,harry);

    temp=pop(harry);
    push(temp,monk);

    temp=pop(harry);
    push(temp,monk);

    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
    printf("%d\t%d\n",harry.arr[i],monk.arr[i]);
    return 0;
    }

    int pop(struct bag name)
    {
    int temp=name.arr[name.top];
    name.top=(name.top)-1;
    return temp;
    }

    void push(int data,struct bag name)
    {
    name.top=(name.top)+1;
    name.arr[name.top]=data;
    }
```

After analysing the code I found that each time I called function,

```
    void push(int data,struct bag name)
```

the *value* of the ***name**.top* was changed to from -1 to 0 but was reverted back to -1 when it was called again. Hence any vaue assigned to ***harry**.arr[**harry**.top]* was ultimately assigned to the array ***harry**.arr[-1]*.
      So, anyone out there with any ideas?

Comment: please indent your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pointers,  as now  you are passing the parameters its gets copied as a local parameters inside the function thus original pass value remains unchanged .

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's because you are never actually modifying the 'stacks' in your functions. C is pass by value, meaning you will have to return the struct 'name' and set it equal to harry and monk within your main.

Such as:

```
harry = push(3,harry);
```

Additionally you can use pointers to simulate a pass by reference scenario like what you are intending with your current code.